# How to use FindByValue with a range of numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to in a single line of code use the "FindByValue" with a range of numbers, instead of typing it 4 times, in this case i want to find by value all the items that start with "02".

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "01")
{
    DropDownList2.Items.FindByValue("0201").Enabled = false;
    DropDownList2.Items.FindByValue("0202").Enabled = false;
    DropDownList2.Items.FindByValue("0203").Enabled = false;
    DropDownList2.Items.FindByValue("0204").Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this Linq code

```
DropDownList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(x => x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "02")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Enabled = false);
```

Comment: It worked but what if i want now all the items started with 02 and 03 how do i do it?

Comment: Simple, add more where clauses `.Where(x => (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "02") || (x.Value.Substring(0, 2) == "03"))`

Comment: Just one last question what does it mean the (0, 2) of the code?

Comment: They are indexes of where to start the substring and the length, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8. So in this case it means "take 2 characters starting from position 0".

Answer (score 1):

You can also Use StartsWith instead of Substring.

```
.Where(x => x.Value.StartsWith("02") || x.Value.StartsWith("03"))
```